# How do I create a software raid on non system drives in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, hard-drive, raid, mdadm

The OS is installed on a standalone SSD, but I have 3x 1TB drives I want to configure in a RAID 5 for docs, applications, games, etc.

How do I do this?

I've searched Google but the only results I found were to create a RAID for the system to be installed on during the initial setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the same thing. I assume now the sda is your ssd harddrive and sdb,sdc and sdd are the 1TB disks:

Create /dev/sdb Partition

Please follow the below instructions to create partition on /dev/sdb drive.

```
# fdisk /dev/sdb
```

Press ‘n‘ for creating new partition.
Then choose ‘P‘ for Primary partition. Here we are choosing Primary because there is no partitions defined yet.
Then choose ‘1‘ to be the first partition. By default it will be 1.
Here for cylinder size we don’t have to choose the specified size because we need the whole partition for RAID so just Press Enter two times to choose the default full size.
Next press ‘p‘ to print the created partition.
Change the Type, If we need to know the every available types Press ‘L‘.
Here, we are selecting ‘fd‘ as my type is RAID.
Next press ‘p‘ to print the defined partition.
Then again use ‘p‘ to print the changes what we have made.
Use ‘w‘ to write the changes.
Note: We have to follow the steps mentioned above to create partitions for sdc & sdd drives too.

```
# mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=5 --raid-devices=3 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdd1
```

now check if raid is done:

```
# cat /proc/mdstat
```

now you can create partitions on /dev/md0

Good luck!

I extracted the instructions from http://www.tecmint.com/create-raid-5-in-linux/

Comment: Sorry, in fdisk, how do I actually set the RAID type to fd? It just interprets fd as f, an unknown command.

Edit: Sorry, worked it out. I needed to press t first.

Answer (score 0):

I havent yet tried this myself but I've heard positive reports.  Have you tried https://help.ubuntu.com/community/btrfs ?

Comment: "under heavy development". Sorry, but this is my production machine, and I'm having enough problems as it is.